# Populate dropdown with Razor in Netcore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm completely new to MVVC and the whole stack on netcore.

I have a form which has text inputs and also has a 3 select dropdowns which need to be populated getting the information hold in another table in the database. I'm stuck in this exact part because I have no idea on how to call the data and then put it in the select. The general idea of the form is the user types in his information and the select some data from the select once he is done the information is sent and then saved in a table in the database.

I currently have this Model for my Cars forms

```
using System;
namespace forms.Models
{
    public class CarQuote
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Brand, Model, Year and Version are select in my UI those 4 values need to be filled getting the information from my Cars table, I created a class to get the information but I do not if is the correct approach.

```
using System;
namespace forms.Models
{
    public class Cars
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is also my Create.cshtml.cs for the Car Quote form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using soofiforms.Models;

namespace forms.Pages.Car
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly soofiforms.Models.ModelContext _context;

        public CreateModel(soofiforms.Models.ModelContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public CarQuote CarQuote { get; set; }
        public Cars Cars { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.CarQuotes.Add(CarQuote);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I connect my Cars table to my CarsQuote form so I can populate my selects? Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the best method is to set it on your view model. In other words, add properties like:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandOptions { get; set; }
```

Then, in your controller, add a private method to populate these option lists:

```
private Task PopulateOptionsAsync(CarQuote model)
{
    model.BrandOptions = await _context.Brands.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name
    }).ToListAsync();

    // etc
}
```

Call that then in your action before return the model to the view. It's best as a private method, as then you can share it between the GET and POST versions of your action. Then, finally, in your view:

```
<select asp-for="Brand" asp-items="@Model.BrandOptions"></select>
```

An alternative approach is to use view injection with a custom service. I personally don't like adding logic like this to a view, but Microsoft does present it as a possible option. Basically, you just create a service class that has methods to return your options:

```
public class CarQuoteOptionsService
{
    private readonly ModelsContext _context;

    public CarQuoteOptionsService(ModelsContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public Task<List<SelectListItem>> GetBrandOptionsAsync =>
        _context.Brands.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        }).ToListAsync();

    // etc
}
```

Then register that in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<CarQuoteOptionsService>();
```

Finally, inject it into your controller and use it at will:

```
@inject CarQuoteOptionsService OptionsService

...

<select asp-for="Brand" asp-items="@(await OptionsService.GetBrandOptionsAsync())"></select>
```